# trying to make a simple image viewer in perl gtk2

Tags: perl, user-interface, gtk

I am trying to make a simple image viewer where you put the filename of an image including its extension but the image doesn't pack in the Main window

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Glib qw/TRUE FALSE/;
use Gtk2 '-init';

my $window=Gtk2::Window->new();
$window->set_title("Image Resizer");
$window->signal_connect('delete_event',sub{Gtk2::main_quit;});

my $vbox1=Gtk2::VBox->new;
my $label=Gtk2::Label->new("Image Filename: ");
my $entry=Gtk2::Entry->new;
my $button=Gtk2::Button->new("Submit");

$button->signal_connect(clicked=>sub{
    my $string=$entry->get_text;
    my $label1=Gtk2::Label->new("$string");
    $vbox1->add($label1);
    my $pbuf=Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf->new_from_file_at_size("$string", 200, 200);
    my $image=Gtk2::Image->new_from_pixbuf($pbuf);
    $vbox1->add($image);
});
$vbox1->add($label);
$vbox1->add($entry);
$vbox1->add($button);
$window->add($vbox1);
$window->show_all;
Gtk2->main;
```

I am making this example as a part of a perl/gtk2 tutorial but can't figure out the source of the bug.

Answer (score 2):

It does pack; you need to explicitly call `show_all` on any widgets you add after the window has already been shown (in this case, to `$label1` and `$image`).

Comment: thanks my man! thats the solution, i add $window->show_all in anon sub. Cheers! :)

Comment: If the above answer solves your problem then you should mark it as an "accepted answer". http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png